# PHP Build a hierarchy set then insert data from a second table

Tags: php, mysql

Ive been trying to figure this out for the better half of two months and not found a solution. I can find plenty of information for building the data for my Types table using recursive function but not for my actual data table. I could be using the wrong terminology. I want to add this is not for building a menu but for building dynamic forms into sections.

If I drop the parent column I can get things to work but I need the extra level.

These are the test tables

```
types
=====
id  name        parent
1   module1     0
2   module2     0
3   component1  1
4   component2  1
5   component3  2
6   component4  2

items
=====
id  name        type_id
1   item1       3
2   item2       3
3   item3       4
4   item4       4
5   item5       5
6   item6       5
7   item7       6
8   item8       6
```

The result Im trying to achieve

```
desired output
==============

module1
    component1
        item1
        item2
    component2
        item3
        item4
module2
    component3
        item5
        item6
    component4
        item7
        item8
```

Any solution to this kind of problem? Table changes, links, or examples? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't the following query work or am I misunderstanding your question?

```
SELECT
    t2.`name` AS 'module',t1.`name` AS 'component',i.`name` AS 'item'
FROM (SELECT * FROM `types` WHERE `parent`>0)  t1
INNER JOIN `types` t2 ON t1.`parent`=t2.`id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN  `items` i ON i.`type_id`=t1.`id`
```

**EDIT:** Changed `` WHERE `parent`!=0 `` into `` WHERE `parent`>0 `` since an id by default will be greater than 0 (and typically -unless set explicitly- a negative integer is an invalid id).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [nested sets model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) to represent hierarchies. That way, you can do away with the recursive call.

Another thing that you can do, is create an extra table to handle to handle the "is-a-child" relationship with a transitive closure, i.e. then you have *all* `is-a-descendant-of` relationships between the nodes.